# sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder: using drop and handle_unknown='ignore'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have some `pandas.Series` – `s`, below – that I want to one-hot-encode. I've found through research that the `'b'` level is not important for my predictive modeling task. I can exclude it from my analysis like so:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

s = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c']).values.reshape(-1, 1)

enc = OneHotEncoder(drop=['b'], sparse=False, handle_unknown='error')
enc.fit_transform(s)
# array([[1., 0.],
#        [0., 0.],
#        [0., 1.]])
enc.get_feature_names()
# array(['x0_a', 'x0_c'], dtype=object)
```

But when I go to transform a new series, one containing both `'b'` and a new level, `'d'`, I get an error:

```py
new_s = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']).values.reshape(-1, 1)
enc.transform(new_s)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/Users/user/Documents/assets/envs/data-science/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_encoders.py", line 390, in transform
>       X_int, X_mask = self._transform(X, handle_unknown=self.handle_unknown)
>     File "/Users/user/Documents/assets/envs/data-science/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_encoders.py", line 124, in _transform
>       raise ValueError(msg)
>   ValueError: Found unknown categories ['d'] in column 0 during transform

This is to be expected since I set `handle_unknown='error'` above. However, I'd like to completely ignore all classes except for `['a', 'c']` in both the fitting and subsequent transforming steps. I tried this:

```py
enc = OneHotEncoder(drop=['b'], sparse=False, handle_unknown='ignore')
enc.fit_transform(s)
enc.transform(new_s)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/Users/user/Documents/assets/envs/data-science/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_encoders.py", line 371, in fit_transform
>       self._validate_keywords()
>     File "/Users/user/Documents/assets/envs/data-science/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_encoders.py", line 289, in _validate_keywords
>       "`handle_unknown` must be 'error' when the drop parameter is "
>   ValueError: `handle_unknown` must be 'error' when the drop parameter is specified, as both would create categories that are all zero.

It seems this pattern is not supported in scikit-learn. Does anyone know a scikit-learn-compatible pattern to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also approach this using the following:

```py
class IgnorantOneHotEncoder(OneHotEncoder):
    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        try:
            return super().transform(X)
        except ValueError as e:
            if 'Found unknown categories' in str(e):
                X = np.copy(X)
                # Keep track of indices corresponding to unknown categories
                unknown_categories_mask = ~np.isin(X, self.categories_[0]).ravel()
                # Overwrite the unknown categories in the input matrix, X, with the first known category
                X[unknown_categories_mask] = self.categories_[0][0]
                # Transform X, whose categories are all known now
                X = super().transform(X)
                # Overwrite originally unknown-category records with 0 to indicate
                # absence of any value for any category for that feature
                X[unknown_categories_mask, 0] = 0
                return X
            else:
                raise
```

Try it out:

```py
>>> ienc = IgnorantOneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
>>> ienc.fit(s)
IgnorantOneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
>>> ienc.transform(s)
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])
>>> ienc.transform(new_s)
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [`sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer) could work for this use case, as it doesn't have any parameters specifying whether to error-out-on or ignore new classes:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
>>> s = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c']).values.reshape(-1, 1)
>>> enc = LabelBinarizer()
>>> enc.fit_transform(s)
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1]])
>>> enc.classes_
array(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='<U1')
>>> new_s = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']).values.reshape(-1, 1)
>>> enc.transform(new_s)
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: And, yes, I realized this immediately after offering the bounty...

Comment: but as in your first case to drop feature `b` from `pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c'])`, `LabelBinarizer` of `pd.Series(['a', 'c'])` returns `array([[0], [1]])`, not `array([[1., 0.],  [0., 0.],  [0., 1.]])` as you wanted in the question. In other way of `LabelBinarizer`, if you `fit_transform` of `pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c'])` and `transform` on `pd.Series(['a', 'c'])`, it returns `array([[1, 0, 0],, [0, 0, 1]])`. It still not your wanted output as using `OneHotEncoder` with `drop` parameter

Comment: Good point. I guess I could write a class over `LabelBinarizer` that adds a `categories` argument like so, and do something similar do what I did with `IgnorantOneHotEncoder`.